# How to create a single dictionary from the given text and output it as stated using a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

**Given the following information about the planets in our solar system, create a single dictionary. (I put the output below this, sorry I'm new to this probably pointless posting the whole text)**

Mercury

Radius - 2,439.7 km

```
Distance from the sun - 58 million km

Moons - none

Atmosphere? True

Gas planet? False
```

Venus

```
Radius - 6,051.8 km

Distance from the sun - 108 million km

Moons - none

Atmosphere? True

Gas planet? False
```

Earth

```
Radius - 6,371.0 km

Distance from the sun - 150 million km

Moons - Moon

Atmosphere? True

Gas planet? False
```

Mars

```
Radius - 3,396.2 km

Distance from the sun - 207 million km

Moons - Phobos and Deimos

Atmosphere? True

Gas planet? False
```

Jupiter

```
Radius - 69,911 km

Distance from the sun - 483 million km

Moons - Io, Ganymede, Callisto, Europa, Adrastea

Atmosphere? True

Gas planet? True
```

Saturn

```
Radius - 60,268 km

Distance from the sun - 1,400 million km

Moons - Pan, Prometheus, Titan, Phoebe, Rhea

Atmosphere? True

Gas planet? True
```

Uranus

```
Radius - 25,559 km

Distance from the sun - 3,000 million km

Moons - Miranda, Ariel, Umbriel, Titania, Oberon

Atmosphere? True

Gas planet? True
```

Neptune

```
Radius - 24,764 km

Distance from the sun - 4,500 million km

Moons - Triton, Nereid, Proteus, Naiad, Thalassa

Atmosphere? True

Gas planet? True
```

**The program stores the above information in a single dictionary and then prints the contents of the dictionary using a for loop.**

**Sample Output:**

Mercury

Distance from the sun : 58

Radius : 2439.7

Gas planet? : False

Atmosphere? : True

Moons : []

Jupiter

Distance from the sun : 483

Radius : 69911

Gas planet? : True

Atmosphere? : True

Moons : ['Io', 'Ganymede', 'Callisto', 'Europa', 'Adrastea']

Uranus

Distance from the sun : 3000

Radius : 25559

Gas planet? : True

Atmosphere? : True

Moons : ['Miranda', 'Ariel', 'Umbriel', 'Titania', 'Oberon']

Mars

Distance from the sun : 207

Radius : 3396.2

Gas planet? : False

Atmosphere? : True

Moons : ['Phobos', 'Deimos']

Earth

Distance from the sun : 150

Radius : 6371.0

Gas planet? : False

Atmosphere? : True

Moons : ['Moon']

Venus

Distance from the sun : 108

Radius : 6051.8

Gas planet? : False

Atmosphere? : True

Moons : []

Saturn

Distance from the sun : 1400

Radius : 60268

Gas planet? : True

Atmosphere? : True

Moons : ['Pan', 'Prometheus', 'Titan', 'Phoebe', 'Rhea']

Neptune

Distance from the sun : 4500

Radius : 24764

Gas planet? : True

Atmosphere? : True

Moons : ['Triton', 'Nereid', 'Proteus', 'Naiad', 'Thalassa']

**So I'm wondering how I'm going to put the input into a dictionary and then output it as given above, I tried saving it into a dictionary except I think I'm not doing it right because I keep getting syntax errors, I'd appreciate any help!!!, I've been staring at this for a few hours..**

Comment: What exactly have you tried and what errors are you getting?

Comment: How about showing us your code and asking specific questions?

Comment: If you have SyntaxErrors, that's means you've tried something.  (that's good).  But you haven't posted your attempt (not so good).  Post what you've tried and we can try to assist.  We're here to help you along so that you (and others who read this post) can learn.  We're not here to do your homework for you. :)

Comment: Sounds like a job for tuples!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, unless you have been specifically told to use a `Dictionary`, it is the wrong data structure for storing this data. Dictionaries are designed to store key-value pairs of data that are intrinsically linked (like BookTitle:ISBN)

Addendum: While "Radius:2439.7" etc... are examples of key-value pairs, what makes a dictionary unsuitable in this circumstance is the fact that all the pairs are associated with a "meta" definition (in this case all the information pairs are part of a singular planet). If that makes sense.

As each planet has numerous data fields associated with them, what you'd want is to define a `Planet` class that encapsulates all the data inside one object.

Example:

```
class Planet:  
    def __init__(self, name, radius, distFromSun, moons, atmosphere, isGasPlanet):
        """Planet Constructor"""
        self.name = name
        self.radius = radius
        self.distFromSun = distFromSun
        self.moons = moons
        self.atmosphere = atmosphere
        self.isGasPlanet = isGasPlanet

    def __str__(self):
        """Overwrites the string output of the class (what gets called by print())""" 

        return str.format("{0}\n"
                          "Distance from the sun: {1}\n"
                          "Radius: {2}\n"
                          "Gas Planet: {3}\n"
                          "Atmosphere: {4}\n"
                          "Moons: {5}\n",
                          self.name,
                          self.distFromSun,
                          self.radius,
                          self.isGasPlanet,
                          self.atmosphere,
                          self.moons)
```

Which would allow you to define any planets you like and print it easily.

```
merc = Planet("Mercury", 2439.7, 58, [], True, False)

print(merc)
```

would give you.

```
Mercury
Distance from the sun: 58
Radius: 2439.7
Gas Planet: False
Atmosphere: True
Moons: []
```

Moreover classes are extensible, allowing you to build on them. For example, you could implement an `AddMoon()` method that appends a new moon to your "moon array" inside your planet object.